# textblob on spelling correction for custom sentences

Tags: python, r, autocorrect

Can you please tell me how to use textblob in python  for spelling corrections on my  own custom sentences(business related). would be helpful if you can mention any other alternative

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post the code?

Answer (score 5):

If there is someone still interested in this, here are multiple ways to do it. If you want to add custom word on fly you can add it to "textblob.en.spelling". For example:

```
import textblob as tb
tb.Word('sensor').correct()
>>'senior'
```

which is not what I want. To add "sensor" to dictionary:

```
tb.en.spelling.update({'sensor':1})
tb.Word('sensoor').correct()
>> "sensor"
```

There are other ways as well. You can append your custom text data to the `en-spelling.txt` file which is located in textblob library directory.